# Windows 10 shutting down after selecting it from the grub menu

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, boot, grub, dualboot

I am a 16 year old Linux user (Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS), and I have been for the past 2 years. I have been dual booting from my MSI laptop (GS63VR Stealth)

I don't know how it exactly happened, But I just went I to boot up my computer and selected the windows 10 option (like usual), and it started booting but then suddenly my computer shutdown. I tried multiple times and each time my computer would shutdown before the windows loading screen would appear. I would see the MSI loading screen, but then immediately it would shut down.

I tried going to different websites, none had an answer. I went to the grub and selected System Setup, then I tried to restore everything to the default setting, but it did not help, nothing changed. I tried changing how windows 10 booted and nothing changed.

How should I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Well I figured it out. I Managed to change my boot order, shut down my computer, it would then only boot to windows and automatically shut down. So then I accessed the advanced options menu by pressing f12 I believe and then made windows boot by choosing one of the options. (which one I do not remember) Then I updated windows and then changed the boot order putting the grub menu before windows in the boot order. After doing so I was able to access Ubuntu and windows without either one crashing before even booting.

Comment: As you've resolved your issue, please feel free to [accept it as well](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer). This'll mark it as containing solution, which will be helpful for others down the line facing the same issue.